# .NET Core API: Disable multiple route expanding in SwaggerUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (4.0.1)` to generate a simple SwaggerUI for testing like it's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). My ApiController have two routes:

```
[Route("api/values")]
[Route("api/{systemId}/values")]
```

The SwaggerUI displays all controller endpoints two times (one with systemId, one without systemId). This is good, but the problem is, when I click on e.g `/api/values/example` SwaggerUI expands `api/{systemId}/values/example` too. Both endpoints are going to the same public C# method inside the controller, it makes sense why SwaggerUI opens both. But it's annoying and confusing.

Is it possible to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `Name` property to the Route.

```
[Route("api/values", Name = "values1")]
[Route("api/{systemId}/values", Name = "values2")]
```

This will create different ids in the `div` containing the endpoint specifications so it will expand only the one you need.

Comment: There was also a problem with overloaded methods in my controller.